# Firefox browser issue in mac for selenium 3.6, geckodriver 0.19 and eclipse oxyzen tool; firefox 47 version

Tags: selenium-webdriver

### Mac

- Version: 0.19.1
- Platform: mcos Sierra
- Firefox: 47.0
- Selenium: 3.6

### This is the issue..

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z' System info: host: 'Darshans-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:410:539:c982:328d%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '9.0.1' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver remote stacktrace: stack backtrace: 0: 0x10405749e -
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Gecko driver v0.19 is not compatible with FF 47. Per the  [release notes](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.19.0) it requires FF v55 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

From [geckodriver releases](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), with the geckodriver v0.19.0, is recommended to use **Firefox 55.0 (and greater)**.

So, is simple thought that with the 0.19.1 should be (at least) the same. Try to update your firefox.

Comment: @DarshanDdd Happy to help. If this answer helped you to solve your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers